# How to store the resulting string of a SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, winforms

I have a table `TümEnvanter$` which has 2 columns equipment code (`Ekipman`) and their description (`Tanım`).

User chooses the equipment from the combo box, and I want the description of the chosen equipment to appear in the label at the time they choose from combobox.

Here is what I tried:

```
SqlCommand cmdTanim = new SqlCommand("select Tanım from TümEnvanter$ where Ekipman = '" + comboBox_ekipman.Text + "'", connect);
connect.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmdTanim.ExecuteReader();
string tanim = reader.ToString();

labelTanim.Text = "Ekipman Tanımı: "+tanim+" ";
```

When I use this code, I get in the label:

```
Ekipman Tanımı: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: just use 'string tanim =Convert.ToString( reader["Tanım"]);' instead of 'string tanim = reader.ToString(); '

Comment: important: your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Please please learn about SQL injection, and **always** use parameters, not string concatenation. Right now, someone could take over your server completely just using your input box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only expect a single value, then `ExecuteScalar` is much simpler than using a reader, i.e.

```
labelTanim.Text = Convert.ToString(cmdTanim.ExecuteScalar());
```

In general, perhaps consider tools like "Dapper" which would make this simple even in multi-row cases *and* solve the SQL injection problem trivially:

```
string s = connect.QuerySingle<string>(
    "select Tanım from TümEnvanter$ where Ekipman = @val", // command
    new { val = comboBox_ekipman.Text }); // parameters
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try this code, it gathers some good practices, such as:

1) Uses `using` statement to release unamnaged resources (SQL connections, `IDisposable`s in general).

2) Prevents from SQL injection using `Parameters` field of `SqlCommand` object.

Also, I used `ExecuteScalar` method, mentioned by @MarcGravell, which simplifies the code.

```
public void SqlConn()
{
    string tanim = null;
    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdTanim = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmdTanim.Connection = connect;
            cmdTanim.CommandText = "select Tanım from TümEnvanter$ where Ekipman = @param";
            cmdTanim.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox_ekipman.Text;
            connect.Open();

            tanim = (string)cmdTanim.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    labelTanim.Text = "Ekipman Tanımı: " + tanim + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
// wrap IDisposable into using
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Put_Connection_String_Here"))
{
    connect.Open();

    // Make SQL readable and parametrized
    string sql = 
      @"select Tanım 
          from TümEnvanter$ 
         where Ekipman = @prm_Ekipman";  

    // wrap IDisposable into using 
    using (SqlCommand cmdTanim = new SqlCommand(sql, connect))
    {   
        //TODO: explicit typing Add(..., DbType...) is a better choice then AddWithValue
        cmdTanim.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Ekipman", comboBox_ekipman.Text);

        // We want one record only; ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteReader() 
        // String interpolation shortens the code
        labelTanim.Text = $"Ekipman Tanımı: {cmdTanim.ExecuteScalar()} ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead by using the `reader()` method of `SqlDataReader` to read and access the contents of the SqlDataReader.

```
SqlCommand cmdTanim = new SqlCommand("select Tanım from TümEnvanter$ where Ekipman = '" + comboBox_ekipman.Text + "'", connect);
connect.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmdTanim.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows){
    reader.read();
    string tanim = reader.ToString();
    labelTanim.Text = "Ekipman Tanımı: "+tanim+" ";    
}
```

Hope this code snippet works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code :

```
SqlCommand cmdTanim = new SqlCommand("select Tanım from TümEnvanter$ where Ekipman = '" + comboBox_ekipman.Text + "'", connect);
connect.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmdTanim.ExecuteReader();
string tanim = string.Empty;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        tanim=  reader["Tanım"].ToString()
    }

labelTanim.Text = "Ekipman Tanımı: "+tanim+" ";
```

Comment: `if (reader.Read()) {...}` instead of `while`; `labelTanim.Text = $"Ekipman Tanımı: {tanim}";` string interpolation is more readable.

Comment: actually, I just gave him sample code. Because he can get multiple rows as well. He can apply conditions according to his requirement.

Comment: this is bad code and should not be encouraged; multiple critical failures, including leaving in the SQL injection, and failing to dispose either the command or the reader.